# Calculating Options P&L on UK stocks

Tags: put-options

Am I correct in thinking that in the UK stocks trade in pence i.e. a value of say 455 would be £4.55. Also stock options on UK based stocks (on the LSE) are for 1,000 shares.

If so, is the following the correct calculation for the profit on a long put position.

Given:

Stock XYZ at 500
Strike = 400
Cost per contract  = 28 
No contracts traded = 1

Then the net spend = £280

P&L if stock goes to 200 = ((400 - 200)-28)*1000 / 100 = £1,720

This is entirely theoretical, but just want to check I have the profit calculation correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The London Stock Exchange stock option contract specifications are listed on their website and do indeed state a multiplier of 1,000 and price value of 0.01 = 10 pence.

https://www.lseg.com/sites/default/files/content/documents/LSEG_UK_STOCK_OPTIONS_FACTSHEET_03.pdf

Comment: thanks. Therefore the P&L calculation is correct?

Comment: Assuming you do reach maturity in those conditions, that looks about right. If this is before maturity then this is not right.